# Reading off of MDADM drives after server died

Tags: raid, mdadm

I had a 2-drive RAID-1 array running on ubuntu, which I had forgotten about. The host I was running them on is now dead, leaving me with these two disks. How can I get data off of them? If I dump them- using dd or the such- how can I read that data in a useful format?

Comment: `mdadm` has no problem with reading from and creating a device for an array from a different host.  Have you scanned and/or checked `/proc/mdstat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mdadm` stores all the array data on the disks themselves and is highly portable between the same or newer versions. Assuming the mirroring was up-to-date, you can even read the data off a single disk via e.g. a USB adapter. (Of course, having backups would reduce the need to do any of this).

All of these steps could be done from a running system but a LiveCD etc. will work just about as well:

1. Attach the drives to the system you want to use to recover the data
2. Find the partition/disk info with `dmesg` output, `sudo fdisk -l` etc.
3. Find the `mdadm` metadata from the disks (use your own disk values here):

   ```
   $ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sda1
   $ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb1
   ```

   The "Preferred Minor" value will tell you which array (e.g. `/dev/md0`) the disks were part of.
4. Assemble the array:

   ```
   $ sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
   ```

   If everything is OK, you'll get a message like "md0 started with 2 devices"; check `/proc/mdstat` to be certain.
5. If the array had a partition table, use `fdisk -l` to find it and mount the correct partition (`kpartx` can be useful here); otherwise, simply `mount /dev/md0 /mnt/temp` as appropriate

Mounting a single disk may or may not "just work" as 3dinfluence said, depending on the `mdadm` metadata location; to be sure, you can assemble with a single member using

```
$ mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sda1 --run.
```

Comment: Got it all back this way, worked great just re-creating the array.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With RAID1 you can simply mount the drive as if it were a single drive.

So put the drive in another computer and for instance if the drive was at /dev/sdb run `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/`  You may have to specify the file system.  So `mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/` for instance if the old volume was ext4.